# Связи EntityFrameworkCore DataBaseFirst MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, entity-framework-core

Пытаюсь настроить связи в EF. Сначала была создана БД, потом прописаны классы EF.
Имеем две таблицы:

```
REATE TABLE `remonts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `details` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price_sum` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_mod` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `shop_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id_master` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `client_id` (`client_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `remonts_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`client_id`) REFERENCES `clients` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=266 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `clients` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `telephone` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bike` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `details` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `balance` float DEFAULT '0',
  `discount` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `discount_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Static',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_2` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=215 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Так же имеем два класса

```
public class Remont
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Column("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Column("status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [Column("client_id")]
        public int ClientId { get; set; }

        [Column("details")]
        public string Details { get; set; }

        [Column("user_id")]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Column("price_sum")]
        public decimal PriceSum { get; set; }

        [Column("date_added")]
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }

        [Column("date_mod")]
        public DateTime Updated { get; set; }

        [Column("shop_id")]
        public int ShopId { get; set; }

        [Column("user_id_master")]
        public int MasterId { get; set; }

        [Column("deleted")]
        public int Deleted { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("client_id")]
        public Client Client { get; set; }
     

        //public List<Remont_> RemontTovars { get; set; }

        //[ForeignKey("user_id")]
        //public User User { get; set; }

        //[ForeignKey("shop_id")]
        //public Shop Shop { get; set; }

        //[ForeignKey("user_id_master")]
        // User Master { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class Client
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Column("id")]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; } = "Розничный покупатель";
        public string telephone { get; set; } = String.Empty;
        public string bike { get; set; } = String.Empty;
        public string details { get; set; } = String.Empty;
        public string balance { get; set; } = "0";
        public string discount { get; set; } = "0";
        public string discount_type { get; set; } = "Static";

    }
```

Да, класс клиент создавался раньше, и в нем нормально не прописаны типы данных, но этот класс уже юзается, так что поправлю позже.

Так же имеем тестовый код, которым я пытаюсь проверить работоспособность навигационного свойства.

```
private void Form1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(remontContext.remonts.First().Client.name);
        }
```

Ну и собственно, ошибка.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Да, я вижу что он не может найти колонку `client_id1`. Я использовал поиск во всему проекту и нет, я не знаю где он взял эту единицу в конце. Если закоментить `[ForeignKey("client_id")]`, то EF просто не понимает что это навигационное свойство и оставляет его пустым. Связь в базе данных прописана (вроде, делал первый раз, но все как показывали умные люди).

Добавляю классы контекста

```
public class RemontContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Remont> remonts { get; set; }
        public RemontContext() { }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder ob)
        {
            ob.UseMySQL(MySql.mySqlConnection);
        }
    }
```

```
public class ClientContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Client> clients { get; set; }
        public ClientContext() { }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder ob)
        {
            ob.UseMySQL(MySql.mySqlConnection);
        }
    }
```

UPDATE

Изменил `[ForeignKey("client_id")]` на `[ForeignKey("id")]`
Имеем ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я абсолютно точно нигде не использовал `Remont_id`. Возможно, этой ошибкой EF пытается получить доступ к таблице `Remont` и столбцу `id` , которого соответственно, как и таблицы, нету.

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(remontContext.remonts.First())` тоже даёт ошибку?

Comment: Покажите класс контекста.

Comment: Вообще, нужно использовать либо scaffolding, либо CodeFirst. А вручную создавать и БД, и классы-сущностей - как мы видим, сложное занятие.

Comment: Может, спецы по MySql увидят что-то неправильное. Тут я пас.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov `MessageBox.Show(remontContext.remonts.First())` ошибку не дает, если не считать то, что `remonts` это не строка, и нужно выбрать любой строковый параметр и вывести его сообщением. Плюс добавил классы контекста. 

В целом, буду ожидать еще мнений или правок, а пока постараюсь понять, почему не работает `scaffold`

Comment: Хорошо. Теперь пробуем `remontContext.remonts.Include(r => r.Client).First().Client)` - есть ошибка?

Comment: Э-э-э... Сделайте один контекст, в котором два DbSet: Clients и Remonts. И все остальные таблицы добавляйте в этот же контекст.

Comment: Аналогичная ошибка, как я понимаю, ошибка это появляется на этапе создания класса Remont, EF пытается присвоить значение свойству Client и вылазит ошибка. Знаете, я вас обманул, ответ на первый комментарий да, ошибка есть. Ее нету, если убрать [ForeignKey("client_id")]

Comment: В атрибуте `[ForeignKey]` указывается имя _свойства_ сущности, а не имя _колонки_ таблицы. / Уберите его и попробуйте запрос с `Include`.

Comment: [Scaffolding MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core-scaffold-example.html)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала скажу, что я не являюсь специалистом по MySql, но всё же могу отметить наличие ошибок в DDL-скриптах.
В частности, для хранения явно денежных величин задан тип `float`, хотя нужно `decimal`.
Мне непонятно наличие `` UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`) `` и `` UNIQUE KEY `id_2` (`id`) ``.
Оставим это на совести автора.

---

Переходим к коду C#.

Если уж вы взялись вручную создавать код сущностей, то вооружитесь таблицей маппинга типов MySql в типы .NET.

| MySql | .NET |
| --- | --- |
| bool, boolean, bit(1) | System.Boolean |
| tinyint | System.SByte |
| tinyint unsigned | System.Byte |
| smallint, year | System.Int16 |
| int, integer, smallint unsigned, mediumint | System.Int32 |
| bigint, int unsigned, integer unsigned, bit | System.Int64 |
| float | System.Single |
| double, real | System.Double |
| decimal, numeric, dec, fixed, bigint unsigned, float unsigned, double unsigned, serial | System.Decimal |
| date, timestamp, datetime | System.DateTime |
| datetimeoffset | System.DateTimeOffset |
| time | System.TimeSpan |
| char, varchar, tinytext, text, mediumtext, longtext, set, enum, nchar, national char, nvarchar, national varchar, character varying | System.String |
| binary, varbinary, tinyblob, blob, mediumblob, longblob, char byte | System.Byte[] |
| geometry | System.Data.Spatial.DbGeometry |

Не создавайте отдельные классы контекста для каждой таблицы. В одном контексте нужно создать несколько свойств `DbSet`.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Remont> Remonts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder ob)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Причём соблюдайте общепринятый нейминг: PascalCase для свойств.

---

Теперь разберёмся, откуда в исключении появлялась колонка `r.client_id1`.
В классе `Remont` на свойство `Client` вы навесили атрибут `[ForeignKey("client_id")]`, что и является причиной ошибки.
Этот атрибут должен указывать на **свойство** класса, а не на колонку в таблице БД. А свойство у нас называется `ClientId`.  Т. к. провайдер БД не может найти свойство с именем `client_id`, он создаёт [теневое свойство](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties) с таким именем. И при явном указании атрибута внешнего ключа с совпадающим именем к нему добавляется суффикс в виде `1` - это и образует имя `client_id1`.

Проще всего удалить атрибут `[ForeignKey("client_id")]`. Провайдер сам разберётся в связях.
То есть в коде должно остаться:

```
[Column("client_id")]
public int ClientId { get; set; }

public Client Client { get; set; }
```

---

Далее нужно освоить [загрузку связанных данных](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/). Чаще всего используется Eager loading - энергичная загрузка. Нужно добавить к запросу `Include`.

```
context.Remonts.Include(r => r.Client).First().Client
```

Это загрузит одновременно данные связанных сущностей `Remont` и `Client`.

---

Чтобы не описывать вручную сущности C#, используйте [scaffolding](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core-scaffold-example.html).

Возможно, в начале будет проще освоить подход Code First.